# Why this for loop show me numbers ahead of 4 and 5?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

first of all sorry for my english. Actually I´m trying to do my first steps in Java, I am reading Java: The Complete Reference, and I´m get stuck  in multidimensional arrays. Now, I think I might understand this concept, but my problem here is in the code that book shows.

```
public class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int twoD [] [] = new int [4] [5];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
            for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
                twoD [i] [j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<5; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD [i] [j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19
```

Why is that? sorry maybe I don´t have clear the concept but If I´m not wrong, the foor loop make a statement  i and j start at 0, the statement defines the condition and the third add 1 more, so I don´t understand why numbers ahead of 4 and 5 appear here.
It´s just frustating start to code and being overwhelmed and I am thinking right now that this is not for me because I don´t understand anything about this code.
Sorry again if this post it´s a dumb question guys.

Comment: Add `System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j + ", k = " + k);` on the line before `twoD [i] [j] = k;`

Comment: I seriously, seriously recommend learning how to use a debugger.  A debugger is your friend.  Just starting out learning a new language, learning the IDE (project manager, editor, compiler/linker/runtime execution, and debugger) is just as important as learning syntax.  Set a breakpoint where you don't understand what is going on and watch as the state (variable values) change.  You gain great insight into what is going on.  You will then quickly become the expert that can help other students as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not very clear with concept of arrays. 
Let us understand that with real life examples :

1D Array :

Lets assume we are placing 7 balls numbered from 11 to 17 in boxes which are numbered from 0 to 6.
Like below:

[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]   -- Size of the Balls

<0,  1,     2,     3,     4,    5,  6 >  -- Numbers on the boxes

This is 1 dimensional array in Java or any programming language.

Code for above:

```
int[] arrayOfBoxes = new int[7];
int valueOnTheBall = 11;
for (int numberOnTheBox=0; numberOnTheBox<7; numberOnTheBox++) 
{
  arrayOfBoxes[numberOnTheBox] = valueOnTheBall;
  valueOnTheBall++;
}
```

2D Array :

Now Lets us assume we are placing these balls in a 2D matrix of 5X4.

Like Below :

[11,   12,   13,  14,   15 ]

*<00,   01,   02,  03,   04 >*

[16,   17,   18,  19,    20]

*<10,  11,   12,   13,   14>*

[21,   22,    23,  24,   25]

*<20,  21,    22,  23,   24>*

[26,   27,    28,    29,   30]

*<30,  31,    32,    33,   34>*

You can think of it as ArrayofArrays and there are 4 arrays, each of size 5.

Pay special attention to the way, indexes are done here.

Code for Above :

```
int arrayNumber;
int indexOfEachArray;

int[][] arrayMatrix = new int[4][5];

int sizeOfTheBall = 11;

for(arrayNumber = 0; arrayNumber < 4; arrayNumber++) 
{
    for(indexOfEachArray=0; indexOfEachArray < 5; indexOfEachArray++)
     {
         arrayMatrix [arrayNumber][indexOfEachArray] = sizeOfTheBall;
          sizeOfTheBall++;
      }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Also there are numerous resources available online, which you can go through.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `k` to the [i][j] element of the 2D array.

Since `k` is declared outside of any loop, it goes from 0 to `(i*j - 1)` - 0..19.

So you have your indices `i=0,1,2,3` and `j=0,1,2,3,4` but the values `k` are `0,1,2...19`

Answer (score 0):

At first i reccomend for you always added curly brackets for every loop and "if" statement. If you don't do that the loop will run only for one code line belowe it.Even if you understand how it's working you can always forgot and have more problem because of that in the future.

`k` is increased every time when loop with variable `j` is iterated.

`j` is iterated 5 times but it's in upper loop which is terated 4 times. So 4x5 = 20 so you have 20 numbers from 0 to 19.